# How to subset my data with eliminating repeated observations

Tags: r, subset

How can I erase repeated observations of IGM?  I want to make following data as one IGM per one county.

I tried

```
    data$GM[data$county]
```

But it didn't work, because I need a row number inside [], not a county number. How can I match one GM per one county?

To be clear,
I want to make this data

```
   county cd110 repvote   state  GM  gini
2    1001   102       1 Alabama 38.4 0.381
3    1001   102       1 Alabama 38.4 0.381
4    1003   101       0 Alabama 39.6 0.491
5    1003   101       0 Alabama 39.6 0.491
9    1003   101       0 Alabama 39.6 0.491
13   1003   101       1 Alabama 39.6 0.491
```

to following data.

```
  county cd110 repvote   state  GM  gini
   1001   102       1 Alabama 38.4 0.381
   1003   101       0 Alabama 39.6 0.491
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, but see the `duplicated` and `unique` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `duplicated` function to get the first observation for each county:

```
dat[!duplicated(dat$county),]
#   county cd110 repvote   state   GM  gini
# 2   1001   102       1 Alabama 38.4 0.381
# 4   1003   101       0 Alabama 39.6 0.491
```