# Extracting data based on observation values

Tags: r, unique, subset

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
deltnr  us      stone_ny        stone_mobility
1535    63  no_stone    NA          1994-09-21  male    60
1536    61  no_stone    NA          1983-09-06  male    60  
1536    62  no_stone    NA          1988-08-18  male    60
1536    63  stone       mobile      1994-03-04  male    70
154     61  no_stone    NA          1983-06-22  male    40
154     62  no_stone    NA          1988-06-08  male    45
1543    61  no_stone    NA          1983-08-17  female  30
1543    62  no_stone    NA          1988-08-17  female  35
1336    61  no_stone    NA          1983-08-22  male    60
1336    62  stone       mobile      1988-11-04  male    65
```

I want to extract all unique observations with deltnr and "stone" in the stone_ny variable. My problem lies with the fact that there are multiple observations for every deltnr. I have tried unique() and subset() with no luck.

Comment: a `dput` of your data frame might make those columns a bit more decipherable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to subset my data with eliminating repeated observations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927273/how-to-subset-my-data-with-eliminating-repeated-observations)

Comment: @Daniel Suppose you have multiple `stone` in `stone_ny` for a `deltnr` group and the other columns are different.  In that case, which of the observation/row do you select?  `unique(dat[dat$stone_ny=="stone",])` would give you multiple `stone` per `deltnr` group.

Comment: I would like to select the first and only one of "us". Exactely this is where I go wrong. You know the way out?

Comment: @Daniel Does it mean that if you have two `us` with `65` and `70` with `stone` for `1336`, would you select the first or both the observation?  I guess you meant the first observation when both `us` are the same?

Comment: The variable us can have three different values (61, 62 and 63), but i am only interested in one of them. So yes, I am only interested in the first observation of "stone" for deltnr "1336".

Comment: @Daniel In that case, the solution posted by me would solve it.

Comment: @Daniel: You should accept/upvote solutions that solved your problem or helped you.

Comment: Just approved:) Thank you for the reminder. I am new to this forum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`

```
    library(dplyr)
    dat %>% 
        group_by(deltnr) %>%
        filter(stone_ny=="stone") %>% #assuming that there are no trailing or leading spaces
        do(head(.,1))
```

gives the output

```
     # deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility       date  sex val
    #1   1336 62    stone         mobile 1988-11-04 male  65
    #2   1536 63    stone         mobile 1994-03-04 male  70
```

Using `data.table`

```
     library(data.table)
      unique(setDT(dat)[stone_ny == "stone"], by="deltnr") #updated after @Arun's comments
      #   deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility       date  sex val
      #1:   1536 63    stone         mobile 1994-03-04 male  70
      #2:   1336 62    stone         mobile 1988-11-04 male  65
```

or you can use `base R`

```
    subset(subset(dat, stone_ny=="stone"), 
             ave(seq_along(us), deltnr, FUN=seq_along)==1)
     #    deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility       date  sex val
    #4    1536 63    stone         mobile 1994-03-04 male  70
    #10   1336 62    stone         mobile 1988-11-04 male  65
```

#### data

I added some column names in your data

```
 dat <- structure(list(deltnr = c(1535L, 1536L, 1536L, 1536L, 154L, 154L, 
 1543L, 1543L, 1336L, 1336L, 1336L), us = c(63L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
 61L, 62L, 61L, 62L, 61L, 62L, 63L), stone_ny = c("no_stone", 
 "no_stone", "no_stone", "stone", "no_stone", "no_stone", "no_stone", 
 "no_stone", "no_stone", "stone", "stone"), stone_mobility = c(NA, 
 NA, NA, "mobile", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "mobile", "mobile"), date = c("1994-09-21", 
 "1983-09-06", "1988-08-18", "1994-03-04", "1983-06-22", "1988-06-08", 
 "1983-08-17", "1988-08-17", "1983-08-22", "1988-11-04", "1988-11-05"
 ), sex = c("male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", 
 "female", "male", "male", "male"), val = c(60L, 60L, 60L, 70L, 
 40L, 45L, 30L, 35L, 60L, 65L, 66L)), .Names = c("deltnr", "us", 
 "stone_ny", "stone_mobility", "date", "sex", "val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -11L))
```

Comment: I think the `data.table` solution is: `unique(setDT(dat)[stone_ny == "stone"], by="deltnr")`. No idea why you subset in `j`, and use it again in `i`... and why `.SD`..

Comment: @Arun Thanks. I think I messed up with the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

You first want to get rid of any rows that have "no_stone" in the `stone` column by using something like

```
good_rows <- grepl("\\bstone\\b", df$stone_ny)
```

Then use `unique()` to get only the unique entries

```
unique(df[good_rows, ])
#    deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility
# 4    1536 63    stone         mobile
# 10   1336 62    stone         mobile
```

Note that I removed the last three columns because they did not have names in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> ddf2 = ddf[ddf$stone_ny=='stone',]
> ddf2[!duplicated(ddf2$deltnr),]
   deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility      
4    1536 63    stone         mobile 
10   1336 62    stone         mobile
```